# Substrate node tempalate Facing error converting chainSpec.json to raw format

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-contracts-node

I am using substrate node-template for my blockchain, I want run with my own accounts, for some reason below code converting chainSpec.json raw format is throwing error.

macOS: : `Apple M1 pro Ventura 13.2.1`

```
installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-05-15-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-10-30-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-2022-10-30-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.66.0-nightly (5e9772042 2022-10-29)
```

Converting Raw Format

```
./target/release/node-template build-spec --chain=customSpec.json --raw --disable-default-bootnode > customSpecRaw.json
```

```
Error: Service(Other("Error parsing spec file: trailing characters at line 30 column 13"))
2023-03-29 19:06:14 Building chain spec
```

```
{
  "name": "development",
  "id": "dev",
  "chainType": "Development",
  "bootNodes": [],
  "telemetryEndpoints": null,
  "protocolId": null,
  "properties": {
    "ss58Format": 42,
    "tokenDecimals": "8",
    "tokenSymbol": "TOKEN"
  },
  "codeSubstitutes": {},
  "genesis": {
    "runtime": {
      "system": {
        "code": "code hash is huge so removed"
      },
      "aura": {
        "authorities": [
          "5G23QwkKM3u1ssrkZW4UYayBmnSV2VtetgnSFhhWpdjACe9N",
          "5Hp4YMLZBEveQQUwiVcYCFYSngmFiWUaspKGEzLepuNXE5C1"
        ]
      },
      "grandpa": {
        "authorities": [
          [
            "5Cx5UcnGQMRNtKh63UR5BYMh3SAg3ivKh5wSki24wchvZyGo",
            1,
            "5DHXJTByBPsUf7xRzJXtBAAFdtF26pyi4iYZccNzHFxM5kDa",
            10
          ]
        ]
      },
      "balances": {
        "balances": [
          ["5G23QwkKM3u1ssrkZW4UYayBmnSV2VtetgnSFhhWpdjACe9N", 1000000000000],
          ["5Hp4YMLZBEveQQUwiVcYCFYSngmFiWUaspKGEzLepuNXE5C1", 1000000000000],
          ["5FLSigC9HGRKVhB9FiEo4Y3koPsNmBmLJbpXg2mp1hXcS59Y", 1000000000000]
        ]
      },
      "transactionPayment": {
        "multiplier": "1000000000000000000"
      },
      "sudo": {
        "key": "5G23QwkKM3u1ssrkZW4UYayBmnSV2VtetgnSFhhWpdjACe9N"
      },
      "assets": {
        "assets": [],
        "metadata": [],
        "accounts": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You must have entered any parameter wrong can you share your custom spec file here

Comment: @ShubhamGupta, I have updated my chain-spec.

Comment: try changing grandpa authority value at line 31 to 1 instead of 10

Answer (score 1):

The error was in the line number 31

From this

```
"grandpa": {
        "authorities": [
          [
            "5Cx5UcnGQMRNtKh63UR5BYMh3SAg3ivKh5wSki24wchvZyGo",
            1,
            "5DHXJTByBPsUf7xRzJXtBAAFdtF26pyi4iYZccNzHFxM5kDa",
            10
          ]
        ]
      },
```

Update to this

```
"grandpa": {
        "authorities": 
    [["5Cx5UcnGQMRNtKh63UR5BYMh3SAg3ivKh5wSki24wchvZyGo",1,], 
    ["5DHXJTByBPsUf7xRzJXtBAAFdtF26pyi4iYZccNzHFxM5kDa",10] ]
   },
```